# Bash .переименовать процесс

Tags: bash

Доброго времени суток.Возможно ли через консоль сменить имя процесса ?

Comment: Привидите пример - есть, желаемое.

Comment: каким вообще образом вопрос связан с программой *bash*?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin метка `троян` будет более к месту?

Comment: @edem, давно пора создать метку `хтнзч` («хочу того не знаю чего»)

Answer (score 2):

если речь про операционную систему *gnu/linux*, то процессы в ней имеют не «имена», а номера.

сменить этот номер, не внося изменений в программу *linux*, невозможно.

---

если же вы подразумевали команду, которой был запущен данный процесс, и которую можно прочитать из псевдофайла `/proc/номер-процесса/cmdline`, то, как можно убедиться, этот файл имеет только биты чтения:

```
$ stat -c '%A' /proc/$$/cmdline
-r--r--r--
```

то есть, опять-таки, без внесения изменений в программу *linux*, изменить выдаваемый текст невозможно.

Comment: root разве не поможет перезаписать файл?

Comment: @AndrioSkur, а вы проверьте. это во-первых, несложно. а во-вторых, не придётся верить мне на слово.